# Blank icon overlay for synced folders and files?

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive, sharepoint

[image]

You can see the actual icons behind the overlay.  Also when I first load the contents of the folder the correct icons show.  I'm assuming this is the green/yellow dot to show sync status.  This started happening after upgrading Office from 2013 to 2016.

Ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Have you rebuilt the [icon cache](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-the-icon-cache-windows)?

Answer (score 0):

[This fix from MS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3079213) seems to have worked, but after applying it Explorer performance was abysmal and I had to reboot.

You can download the automatic utility or follow the steps below:

> **Easy fix 20152**
>
> **Important**  Follow the steps in this section carefully.
>   Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly.
>   Before you modify it, [back up the registry for restoration](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322756) in case
>   problems occur.
>
> **Warning** Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry
>   incorrectly by using Registry Editor or by using another method. These
>   problems might require you to reinstall the operating system.
>   Microsoft cannot guarantee that these problems can be resolved. Modify
>   the registry at your own risk.
>
> If you want to have OneDrive icon overlays take priority over other
>   applications, consider the following workarounds.
>
> **Workaround 1: Update the registry**
>
> Update the registry to give priority to OneDrive for Business.
>   Priority is based on the alphabetical order of the entries. Use this
>   workaround if you want to enable OneDrive for Business to show its
>   icon overlays. This workaround will suppress other icon overlays from
>   other programs, and some programs in future updates may re-suppress
>   OneDrive for Business icon overlays.
>
> To update the registry, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open registry editor.
>
>    **Windows 10:** In the search box on your task bar, type
>      regedit.exe, and then press Enter. If you're prompted for an
>      administrator password or confirmation, type the password, or provide
>      confirmation.
>      **Windows 8 and 8.1:** Swipe in from the right side
>      of the screen, and then tap Search. Or, point to the upper-right
>      corner of the screen, and then click Search. In the search box, type
>      regedit.exe, and then press Enter. If you're prompted for an
>      administrator password or confirmation, type the password, or provide
>      confirmation.
>      **Windows 7:** Click Start, type regedit.exe in the
>      search box, and then press Enter. If you're prompted for an
>      administrator password or confirmation, type the password, or provide
>      confirmation.
> 2. Move to the following folder, and then expand it:
>
> > `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`
>
> 3. Rename the following registry keys. To do this, right-click the
>      folder, select **Rename**, and then rename the folder. When you rename the
>      folder, add two spaces at the beginning of the name.
>
>    **Note** You may have to add more than one spaaaaaace to the beginning of
>      the folder name depending whether other icon overlay providers have
>      added leading spaces to their icon overlay names.
>
>    [image]
>
>    **Note** In this example,  represents two spaces
>      in the renamed folder name.
> 4. On the **View** menu, click **Refresh** to verify
>      that the renamed keys now appear at the top of the list.
> 5. Exit Registry
>      Editor, and then restart your computer.
>
> **Workaround 2: Uninstall unused applications**
>
> Consider uninstalling applications that heavily use icon overlays that
>   you aren’t using. This workaround will unregister the icon overlays
>   that are used by those applications and could enable OneDrive for
>   Business to display icon overlays again. You may have to restart your
>   computer after you uninstall the applications for the icon overlays to
>   reappear.